# Variable not in scope in nested where

Tags: haskell

I'm implementing luhn algorithm, here's the code I have so far:

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn xs = ((evens + odds) `mod` 10) == 0 where
      evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
      odds = sum [luhnDouble x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 /= 0] where
            reversed_indexed_xs = zip (reverse xs) [0..]
```

error I'm getting is

```
 Variable not in scope: reversed_indexed_xs :: [(a, Integer)]
   |
33 |       evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

despite `reversed_indexed_xs` being defined in nested `where` statement.
I assume my problem is with indentation, any help?

Comment: Well the `where` is scoped in the `odds` statement, not the `evens` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You scoped the `where` with the `odds` statement, not the `even`:

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn xs = ((evens + odds) `mod` 10) == 0 where
      evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
      odds = sum [luhnDouble x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 /= 0] where
            reversed_indexed_xs = zip (reverse xs) [0..]
```

Since the `reversed_indexed_xs` uses no variables bounded to `odds`, we can simply put it on the same level as `evens` and `odds`:

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn xs = ((evens + odds) `mod` 10) == 0 where
      evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
      odds = sum [luhnDouble x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 /= 0]
      reversed_indexed_xs = zip (reverse xs) [0..]
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need another nested `where`, just do

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn xs = ((evens + odds) `mod` 10) == 0 where
      evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
      odds = sum [luhnDouble x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 /= 0]
      reversed_indexed_xs = zip (reverse xs) [0..]
```

The problem is that when you write `X where Y`, the definitions in `Y` can be used only in the expression `X`. In your case, `reversed_indexed_xs` can be used only in the scope of the definition of `odds`.

Answer (score 7):

The nested `where` is scoped only to the definition under which it's nested - i.e.  to `odds`, - but you're using it in both `evens` and `odds`. It's in scope for `odds`, but not for `evens`.

To use it in both `evens` and `odds`, you can just define it at the same level, no nesting required:

```
luhn :: [Int] -> Bool
luhn xs = ((evens + odds) `mod` 10) == 0 where
      evens = sum [x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 == 0]
      odds = sum [luhnDouble x | (x,i) <- reversed_indexed_xs, i `mod` 2 /= 0]
      reversed_indexed_xs = zip (reverse xs) [0..]
```